# Getting tag and value from XML file

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I got a xml config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Config>
    <useProxy>true</useProxy>
    <proxyReqPass>true</proxyReqPass>
    <proxyHost>proxy.net.br</proxyHost>
    <proxyUser>admin</proxyUser>
    <proxyPass>12345</proxyPass>
</Config>
```

I have a list of Data() objects, each Data() contains 2 strings, the tag name and the value of the tag. So i want to insert in this list the data of this xml file, like the example:

```
List<Data> data = new ArrayList<Data>();

        File fXmlFile = new File("Config.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList elements = doc.getElementsByTagName("Config");

        for (int i = 0; i < elements.getLength(); i++) {

            Node nNode = elements.item(i);

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                data.add(new Data(eElement.getTagName(), eElement.getTextContent()));

            }
        }
```

And if i print the list:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
                System.out.println("Node: " + list.get(i).getTagName() + " Value: " + list.get(i).getTextContent());
```

I want the result to be:

```
> Node: useProxy Value: true
Node: proxyReqPass Value: true
Node: proxyHost Value: proxy.net.br
Node: proxyUser Value: admin
Node: proxyPass Value: 12345
```

But the result is:

```
> Node: Config Value: 
    false
    false
```

I don´t know where´s my mistake, please somebody help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating over the results of the search for the `<Config>` tag. You should be iterating over the search results children.

```
NodeList configTags = doc.getElementsByTagName("Config");
// assuming there will only be one `Config` node
NodeList elements = configTags.item(0).getChildNodes();

for (int i = 0; i < elements.getLength(); i++) {
   // (everything else looks correct)...
}
```

When you query `getElementsByTagName()`, a NodeList is returned which, in your case should always contains one node, the `<Config>` node. To access the child nodes (`<useProxy>`, etc), you need to get the first Node out of the node list and query for it's children qith `getChildNodes()`.

Comment: Just found the problem, instead using NodeList to the configTags im using Node, but whatever, thanks a lot